# Docker push command is giving error "tag does not exist"

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to push the docker image created on my local to Amazon ECR repository using below command:-

`docker push <<accountid>>.dkr.ecr.<<region>>.amazonaws.com/api:latest`

give below error:-

`tag does not exist: <<accountid>>.dkr.ecr.<<region>>mazonaws.com/api:latest`

Comment: Are you sure you have a 'latest' tag in your docker images ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not tag your image correctly. Just follow the simple steps mentioned in your ECR repo after clicking `view push command` .

General command is this to tag your image

```
docker tag yourLocalDockerImage <accountId>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repoName>:<tag>;
```